# How to list all extensions with command in codespaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code, codespaces

I installed the extension in the codespaces, and the extension is shown in the **browser installed** section. But when I use the command `code --list-extensions`, it didn't show the installed extension. I want to know why and how to show the extensions with commands. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try
code --list-extensions
or to a file for grep after
code --list-extensions>>myExt.txt

Comment: sorry this was for local--not codespaces